# How to Customize More Tabbar TableView Cell for Storyboard iOS 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, tableview, tabbar

I have added 6 or more tabbar on the storyboard. It will automatically generate More Tab.
When I click the more button, I can see other view controller on tableview row cell. But I couldn't change cell view.

How to customize cell view for more tabbar table view?

Best regards.